# How to disable Varnish

Tags: apache-2.2, wordpress, varnish

I have installed Varnish in my WordPress Ubuntu EC2 instance as described in this guide:

http://jeffreifman.com/detailed-wordpress-guide-for-aws/install-varnish/

I do have many issues with Varnish and would like to disable Varnish.

I tried to undo the steps described in the guide, e.g. setting ports from `:8080` back to `:80`, then restarting Apache and rebooting Ubuntu. 
Unfortunately, since my WordPress website does no longer work after these steps, I must have missed something.

When opening my website in a browser, I get the following error message:

```
Error 503 Service Unavailable

Service Unavailable

Guru Meditation:

XID: 513637370
```

What is the correct way to disable (and even uninstall Varnish) from my WordPress installation?

Comment: What do your apache logs say ?

Comment: @lain: Where can I find the apache logs?

Comment: https://www.varnish-cache.org/docs/3.0/tutorial/troubleshooting.html#varnish-gives-me-guru-meditation

Comment: I would suggest checking apache and varnish logs, its been some time since I dealt with Varnish, a quick search lead me to this link, I hope you find this helpful.                               https://www.varnish-cache.org/forum/topic/818

Answer (score 7, accepted):

if you use CentOS or Red Hat, use this:

```
service varnish stop
```

if you want to uninstall varnish, try this:

```
yum erase varnish
```

or refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27739853/varnish-cache-server-error-503-service-unavailable

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the message, it seems you have forgotten to change back varnish port to it's default 6081, so you should edit your `/etc/default/varnish` file and change `VARNISH_LISTEN_PORT` or the `-a` applicable reference.

If you want to uninstall varnish, it should be as easy as `sudo apt-get remove varnish`

Comment: Folks commenting here are assuming a lot of things, in some system setups, if you stop varnish you stop your websites.